Breaker trips after replacing light
3 black wires 3 white wires one black wire is always hot unless the breaker is off. When I wired the light connecting the 3 black wires  to the light and connecting 3 whites together . Turning the switch on trips the breaker

How was it connected before?

Good chance you have a switch loop.
Turn off the breaker and check the wires on the switch.
I am betting you will find a white and black wire on the switch screws.
The white is suppose to be hot to the switch and have black marks at both ends.  The black is your switch hot and goes to the light's black.
The switch white is connected to the always hot in the ceiling.
The third black wire is either connected to the ceiling hot if powering something else(outlet) or to the switch hot if another light on that switch.
The light white is connected to the other whites.
You need to find which black and white comes from the switch, before connecting any whites.

This is a common problem when people replace lights or replace with a ceiling fan. Crip659's answer above is correct.
The National Electrical Code requires the white wire feeding the light switch to be the constant hot (when using NM or MC 2 conductor cable) and be re-identified as a hot wire like black/red/blue but many installers neglect to change the feed to the switch to a color other than white.
Consequently, when people take them apart they put them all back as black and white. This creates a dead short between the constant hot and the neutral when the switch is thrown.
Follow Crip659's instructions to identify which wires go to the switch and re-identify the white with some black/red/blue tape to avoid this problem in the future.
